# Lighttpd Prepending Strings to Certain Files

Tags: php, lighttpd

I have a Mint install (Fantastic stats, if you were wondering) and I would like to move over to Lighttpd for my server needs. Unfortunatly, this means that php_auto_prepend is no longer easily available. I understand that PHP can do this in the php.ini file, but I have areas that can't have this value prepended so that's out of the question. Is there a lighttpd way to prepend my script for my mint install in some files, and have it disabled for others?